# C# asp.net core 2.2 - Get current date time - Not Accurate

Tags: datetime, .net-core, utc, datetimeoffset

I tried everything to get the current year/month/date/hour but it doesn't work. I always get data 1 hour behind. So if it's 17:00 in the Netherlands, I get 16:00. I have tried so many things, but I can't get this fixed.. is it a bug?

I Tried this:

```
string dateTimeNowPlusForecaseHour = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToLocalTime().AddHours(hour).ToString("yyyyMMddhh");
```

And this:

```
string dateTimeNowPlusForecaseHour = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().AddHours(hour).ToString("yyyyMMddhh");
```

And this:

```
string dateTimeNowPlusForecaseHour = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().AddHours(hour).ToString("yyyyMMddhh");
```

And this:

```
string dateTimeNowPlusForecaseHour = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(hour).ToString("yyyyMMddhh");
```

And this:

```
        public string GetForecastTime(int hour)
    {
        // Take amount of seconds elapsed since 1970
        var amountOfSecondsElapsedSince1970 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();

        // Make a Datetime variable (1970 is the start)
        System.DateTime dateTimeNowString = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);

        // Add amountOfSecondsElapsedSince1970 to the date time starting at 1970, + the amount of hours (for each forecast so 0, 1, and 2)
        dateTimeNowString = dateTimeNowString.AddSeconds(amountOfSecondsElapsedSince1970).AddHours(hour).ToLocalTime();

        // This is the dateTime
        string dateRealWeatherForecastTimee = dateTimeNowString.ToString("yyyyMMddhh");

        return dateRealWeatherForecastTimee;
    }
```

Nothing seems to work.

### Update

I tried the following line on a new asp.net core console project (rather than the project I'm working on):

```
    string dateTimeNowPlusForecaseHour = DateTime.Now.AddHours(hour).ToString("yyyyMMddhh");
```

That works! But why doesn't it work for the project I'm working on?

Update2.0:
When I view my timezone of the project, I get GMT which is wrong. When I create a new asp.net core console project and view the timezone, I get w. europe, which gives me the correct time... Why is the timezone wrong? Shouldn't that be correct automatically?

Answer (score 0):

> DateTime.Now returns the current time and day. The struct it returns
>   can be stored as a field or property in a class. We look into this
>   property and its implementation—where it accesses the operating system
>   for the current time.

```
string dateTimeNowPlusForecaseHour = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHH");
```

Comment: But why doesnt this work for me? I still get the incorrect hour.. is it a asp.net core bug?

Comment: no no, verify your computer hour or your server 
DateTime.Now get the current date of your system ( Computer,Server)

Comment: Verify the configuration of your time zone in your computer

Comment: I did verify it, and it's normal.. But if I open a new project, a .net core console project, then it works...

Comment: The time zone is GMZ, which is wrong.. but when I create a new project, the Time zone is w. europe, it shows the correct time!! Why is the timezone wrong on the project i'm working on?

Answer (score -1):

[image: C# DateTime Format]

This screenshot is taken from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1). And I've used almost all of these, which means these are tested and should definitely work. If you still get incorrect hour, please check the time-zone of the server where you're hosting your application.

Comment: The time is incorret for the host and on my dev environment (my pc), so on both environments. I have a feeling it's because of the project, because If i make a new .net core project, I get the correct time...

Comment: You can get the current timezone of your project by using: TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
Please refer to the below link for details if you want to figure out which timezone your dev environment is using,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone.currenttimezone?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you for your response, It shows GMT, but i'm in the Netherlands, so that's wrong, but why does it use that Time Zone, why not my own Time zone? Because when you use DateTime.Now, it should be based on your local timezone right?

Comment: Also, when I create a new asp.net core console project, it shows w. europe as time zone, thats correct!! Why doesn't it dynamically decide what timezone to use in my mainproject..

Comment: Yes, Datetime.Now returns value based on your local timezone. And it's really weird that your main project doesn't use your local timezone. A better approach can be to not rely on Datetime.Now. Instead, go for DateTime.UtcNow. More details here: https://blog.submain.com/4-common-datetime-mistakes-c-avoid/

Comment: Thank you very much, tomorrow I will look deeper into this. Can the problem occur because I make use of docker?

Comment: That's definitely a possibility.

Comment: Hi dear friend
I think this is not your code problem. The `time and date` on your system is not `global`.